# Func / Action delegates with reference arguments/parameters or anonymous functions

Tags: c#, delegates, lambda, inline, anonymous-function

I just wondered, how the exact syntax is for `ref` and `out` parameters for delegates and inline lambda functions.

here is an example

if a function is defined as

```
 public void DoSomething(int withValue) { }
```

a delegate in a function can be created by

```
 public void f()
 {   
     Action<int> f2 = DoSomething;
     f2(3);
 }
```

how is that syntax, if the original function would be defined as

```
 public void DoSomething(ref int withValue) { withValue = 3; }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to define a new delegate type for this method signature:

```
delegate void RefAction<in T>(ref T obj);

public void F()
{
    RefAction<int> f2 = DoSomething;
    int x = 0;
    f2(ref x);
}
```

The reason why the .NET Framework does not include this type is probably because `ref` parameters are not very common, and the number of needed types explodes if you add one delegate type for each possible combination.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use `Action`, `Func<T>`, or the built-in delegates, but need to define your own in this case:

```
delegate void ActionByRef<T>(ref T value);
```

Then, given this, you can have:

```
int value = 3;
ActionByRef<int> f2 = DoSomething;
f2(ref value);
```