# Delegate/Action is not passing value

Tags: c#, callback, delegates

I have a very basic understanding of using this technique so I probably and missing something simple. All I want to do is add a variable that holds the TOTAL items but the variable seems to be getting initialized back to 0 when I check it. My best guess is something is going out of scope and I am losing the value.

1. I call a function that passes a delegate(?)

   ```
   [TestMethod]
   public void Batch_Update_Is_Working()
   {
       DataTable dt = ExcelHelper.ReadAsDataTable(pathFileName);
      EncompassBoxHelper.UpdateBoxes(ec, dt, progess => UpdateProgressBar(pi));
   }
   ```
2. Inside the function I want to pass a value back.

   ```
    public static void UpdateBoxes(EncompassConnection ec, DataTable dt, Action<ProgressInfo> updateProgress)
    {
       Session s = EncompassSession.Instance(ec.Url, ec.Name, ec.Password);

       updateProgress(new ProgressInfo(dt.Rows.Count));
   ```
3. This is where the value is stored. In ItemsTotal. All good so far.

   ```
    public class ProgressInfo
    {
        public int itemsProcessed { get; set; }
        public int itemsTotal { get; set; }

        public ProgressInfo()
        {

        }

        public ProgressInfo(int it)
       {
           itemsTotal = it;
       }
   }
   ```
4. Now when it goes to the callback the value is 0??? pi.itemsProcessed is suppose to be 100.

   ```
   public void UpdateProgressBar(ProgressInfo pi)
   {
       pi.itemsProcessed++;
       Debug.WriteLine("Progress Info.ItemsProcessed: " + pi.itemsProcessed);
       Debug.WriteLine("Progress Info.ItemsTotal: " + pi.itemsTotal);

   }
   ```

Comment: Why do you think `itemsProcessed` will be `100`?  It's initialised as `0` and you increment it by `1`.

Comment: `progess => UpdateProgressBar(pi)` looks strange - could you please confirm that is that you actually have in the test (clearly `pi` would have zero as values assuming it is some sort of instance/static).

Comment: I forgot to mention pi.itemsprocessed is set to 100 in the code. But that value never gets to the end of the code and ends up being 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your

```
EncompassBoxHelper.UpdateBoxes(ec, dt, progess => UpdateProgressBar(pi));
```

to

```
EncompassBoxHelper.UpdateBoxes(ec, dt, UpdateProgressBar);
```

Instead of sending the `UpdateProgressBar()` method to match the delegate expected in `UpdateBoxes` parameter, you're creating a new one by converting lambda expression, telling it to call itself specifically with a parameter of `pi`, instead of the one, that should be passed inside `UpdateBoxes` method (the `new ProgressInfo(dt.Rows.Count)` object).

Comment: Ok looks to be working. So basically I am setting the values inside the method instead of outside with a constructor that I send in the values.   updateProgress(new ProgressInfo(2, dt.Rows.Count));. I am not really sure what progess => UpdateProgressBar(pi) was doing because I still can't get my head around Func/Action/Delegates yet

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your pi variable is not being passed by reference so it is never really getting updated. Honestly changing a value like pi.itemsProcessed++ in your delegate function is not very common although there are ways to do it  [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13923685/func-action-delegates-with-reference-arguments-parameters-or-anonymous-functio).

Once your delegate supports passing in a variable with the "ref" keyword, then you should be able to call your delegate with something like this:

```
progess => UpdateProgressBar(ref pi)
```

You could also make pi a static variable and then it can be updated from your delegate as well so you don't have to worry about passing it around.