# Why does ++ and -- not work in lambda expressions?

Tags: c#, lambda

This drove me a bit nuts. I was trying to create a lambda expression that would reverse my for loops based on a boolean. So if the boolean is true then I would use addition for the loop variable update and vise versa.

This left me with a lambda loooking something like one of these

```
Func<int, int> dirFunc = (n) => n++;
Func<int, int> dirFunc = (n) => n--;
```

Though I would get odd loop errors, I finally realized that `++` and `--` do not seem to work within lambdas, or the way that I think they would have worked.

Why is this?

Comment: can you show the full code? in your code `n` is just a parameter of your lambda, you are not actually changing the value of a variable.

Comment: from a functional programming point of view, postfix `++` is a side-effect, and hence, *shouldn't* be used in lambda expression; yet, that says nothing about your application (C# not being purely functional).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to work fine for me, as `n++` is using the postfix increment operator, it returns the value of `n` before it was incremented, so `dirFunc(2)` returns 2 (If you don't understand this I suggest you read about the differences between prefix and postfix increment operators).

Because `int` is a value type, your lambda is taking a copy of the value not a reference to a variable, so you are incrementing that copy. If you wish to take a reference to a variable you could define a new delegate which takes a ref parameter (see [Func / Action delegates with reference arguments/parameters or anonymous functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13923685/func-action-delegates-with-reference-arguments-parameters-or-anonymous-functio)).

I think you most likely want something like the following:

```
Func<int, int> dirFunc = n => n + 1; // OR Func<int, int> dirFunc = n => n - 1;

for(var i = start; i < end; i = dirFunc(i))
{
}
```

Notice we reassign the value of `i` on each iteration using the newly incremented/decremented result from `dirFunc`

Comment: @MartinMaat That is correct, however there is little point in using `++n` or `--n` when you don't actually care about incrementing/decrementing `n`.

Comment: @MartinMaat Why do you want `n` to change value? You're not doing anything with it. `n+1` is just as many characters and works without updating the variable.

Comment: @Sylwester  Don't look at me, I am just passing by.